# Show that this map is well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Consider the following map:

$$SU(2) \to O_{3}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$$
$$h \mapsto (\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}\;\; \to \;\;\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}} )$$

$$a \to h^{-1}ah$$

where $h$ is a unitary quaternion seen as matrix, so I have proved that the determinant of  $h^{-1}ah$ is $1$ because

$$\det h^{-1}ah=(\det a)(\det h^{-1})(\det h)=1·1·1=1,$$

but how can I prove that this is an orthogonal matrix?

Thanks for your help :)

NOTE: $\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}=\{ bi+cj+dk:b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: I think you also need to show that $h^{-1}ah$ is still purely imaginary.

Comment: Well but I was thinking to do it by hand, this is computing $h^{-1}ah$ explicitly and the inverse, but I don't know if this is a right way, and I think there is something estrange because I am trying to multiply $h^{-1}a$ ,and a is 3 by 3 while $h$ is 2 by 2

Comment: You are right. So I think you need to use the fact that $SU(2)$ can be identified as  unit quiterion. (Or it does not make sense, as you suggest)

Comment: $h^{-1}ah$ is not the element of $O_3$ being defined, $h^{-1}ah$ is an element of $\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}\subset M_2(\Bbb C)$. $End (\Bbb R^3)$ can be identified to $End (\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}})$ by the obvious isomorphism between the underlying vector spaces. Conjugating matrices in $\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$ by an element of $SU(2)$ gives a linear map in $End(\langle i,j,k\rangle_{\mathbb{R}})$. This linear map is the map you want to show is orthogonal.

Comment: But I have the posted map in my notes, so I don't understand where is the mistake :(

Comment: I'd suggest looking at Stillwell's (Naive Lie Theory) or Artin's (Algebra) book if you are having difficulty understanding the definition of the maps.

Comment: So the below is not an answer, or I can put it as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you regard a quaternion $a$ as complex $2 \times 2$ matrices then the square of its norm is the determinant i.e. $\| a \|^2 = \det(a)$. As you already observed $\det(a) = \det(h^{-1}ah)$. Thus, the map $a \to h^{-1}ah$ is linear an preserves norms hence it is orthogonal.

A quaternion $x = x_1 + x_2 i + x_3 j + x_4 k = z_1 + z_2 j$, where $z_1 = x_1 + x_2j$ and $z_2 = x_3 + x_4 j$ is regarded as the following $2 \times 2$ matrix $$ x = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
z_1 & z_2 \\
-\bar{z_2} & \bar{z_1}  \end{array} \right) .$$
Observe that:

1) the span $\langle i,j,k \rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$ of pure quaternions is the set of quaternions $x$ with $\mathrm{trace}(x)=0$.

2) the norm $\|x \|^2 = \det(x)$.

Now if $h = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
h_1 & h_2 \\
-\bar{h_2} & \bar{h_1}  \end{array} \right) $ and $a = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a_1 & a_2 \\
-\bar{a_2} & \bar{a_1}  \end{array} \right)$ are such that $\det(h)=1$ and $\mathrm{trace}(a) = 0$ you have $$ \det(h^{-1} a h) = \det(a) \, \, \, \& \, \, \, \mathrm{trace}(h^{-1}ah) = 0 $$
So the map $a \to h^{-1}ah$ from $\langle i,j,k \rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$ into itself is well defined, linear and preserve the norm. So its matrix, when writen in the orthogonal base $(i,j,k)$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Ok, then I can write it like this and no more computings, right? this should be a complete proof :)

Comment: Well, the quaternion is h :)

Comment: Do my above comment change your answer?

Comment: You have to regard quaternions as $2 \times 2$ complex matrices. Also $a$ is a quaternion. I will edit my answer and add more details.

Comment: Ok :) thanks a lot for tour answer now it is a complete proof :)